# setting flag value base on record exist in another table

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL.

Below are my table structure.

Table : A

```
aId(PK)     aValue1     aValue2
----------------------------------
1           value-a1    value-b1
2           value-a2    value-b2
3           value-a3    value-b3
4           value-a4    value-b4
```

Table: B

```
bId(PK)     aId(FK)     bValue1     bValue2
-----------------------------------------------------
1           1           val-1       value-1
2           1           val-2       value-2
3           2           val-3       value-3
```

How I can achieve below result in single query. 
I want all records from table:A and flag value against each records if relevant record exist in Table:B
I tried INNER JOIN, LEFT / RIGHT but not helping.

RESULT

```
aId     aValue1     aValue2             bId (flag if record exist Y else N)
-----------------------------------------------
1           value-a1    value-b1        Y
2           value-a2    value-b2        Y
3           value-a3    value-b3        N
4           value-a4    value-b4        N
```

My Query: This returning me more than 4 rows. which is wrong

```
    SELECT
c.* , if( d.bId is NULL,'N','Y')
from a c
LEFT JOIN b d ON a.aId = d.aId
```

Comment: Why your left join didn't work? It is the right solution. Can you show your attempt ? Add it on your question.

Comment: @JorgeCampos is right, just use if( bid is NULL,'N','Y') in select for Y or N

Comment: add SQL query stat. problem is .. getting redundant data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the condition to print the `Y` or `N` flag.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* , IF(d.bId is null, 'Y', 'N')
  FROM tableA c
      LEFT JOIN tableB d ON a.aId = d.aId
```

Comment: if TableA has 4 records then query should returning 4 records only and based on those 4 records, flag value Y/N if id exist in second TableB. But query returning redundant data

Comment: Sorry my Bad ... its working don't know why getting wrong last time