# Combine data of three tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working on a SQL-statement which will involve 3 different tables. Below you can see the structure of them with one example data each.

[image]

1. **FOLLOWERS-TABLE**: This table contains information about the current user ('user') following another user ('following')
2. **MESSAGES**: This table contains information about messages of a certain user
3. **LIKES**: This table contains information about who liked other messages. 'idmessage' is the same as the 'id' in the Messages-table

First of all, I wanted to display all the messages of the persons who the user follows. I used this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Messages 
     LEFT JOIN Followers ON Followers.following=Messages.user 
WHERE Followers.user = 'Peter Jackson'
```

This resulted in this:

[image]

It is working. However, in the next step I should add a custom column to it, this must be 'alreadyLiked'. This should check if the user already liked the message. The value must be 'yes' or 'no'. Therefore, information about the Likes-table is needed. I guess I should make another join on 'Likes.idmessage' and 'Messages.id'. But I don't know how to give it a value 'yes' or 'no'. In the end, it should be like this:
[image]

On the server-side I use Node.js and the client-side AngularJS.

Comment: Set up direct indexes and set up forigen keys will help your database work better and be more efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting flag value base on record exist in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906681/setting-flag-value-base-on-record-exist-in-another-table)

Comment: Please read the duplicate linked post, this is an exact duplicate of that issue. aswer: Set a flag in the SQL.

Comment: I can't figure out what the syntax of that solution is with 3 tables. And where do the 'c' and 'd' come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly then this should work:

```
SELECT Messages.*,  Followers.*, 
CASE WHEN Likes.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS alreadyLiked
FROM Messages 
LEFT JOIN Followers ON Followers.following=Messages.user 
LEFT JOIN Likes ON Likes.idmessage = Messages.id
WHERE Followers.user = 'Peter Jackson'
```

The way this works is simply by left joining the Likes table. Now if there is a no link found between the message table and the like table then the fields from the Like table will be null. Then we use the case operator to check each row if any field from the like table is or isn't null.